# Magento Magmi Import Product not show up

Tags: magento, csv, bulk, magmi

I imported items with magmi and it was successful i see it at my inventory at backend but not front end.

I already imported before and thoose work.

Has anybody had this problem before?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried reindexing? If your products are not indexed properly, they won't show up in your categories.

Comment: Are they enabled, is the visibility set correctly, are they in stock?

Comment: are you also setting the is_in_stock flag?  needs to be '1' in the magmi csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some checks you can do to ensure the product appears in the frontend:

1. Make sure you are reindexing all of the index tables after import.
2. Ensure that the product `Status` attribute is set to `Enabled`
3. Make sure the product has a quantity greater than 0.
4. Make sure the availablity is set to `In Stock`
5. Make sure the product is properly assigned to a category.
6. Check and see if the product is correctly assigned to the store/website.

Answer (score 0):

if you can see it at the backend, reindex it and enable the category of products , it will show up immediately